# How to properly create resource for belongsToMany models in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel

So im trying to use "nested" resources to get response like this:

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Name of post 1",
            "description": "nihil",
            "tags": {
               "id": 2,
               "title": "est",
               "slug": "tag-2"
        }
```

but for some reason I always get null after tags. Relation between posts and tags is belongsToMany. My PostResource.php looks like:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'tags' => new TagsResource($this->tag),
        ];
    }
```

and tags TagsResource just:

```
return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
        ];
```

Since it's belongsToMany relation i have additional PostTag table, model that connects these two and i tried to make additional PostTagsResource thinking tables arent directly connected but with no success.
My route returns simple `PostResource::collection($posts);` with get method.

Comment: I’d use Post::with(‘tags’) and get all the tags linked to post and later on move data to resource where you can call data like post->tags() [possibly array] in resource tags as I’ve tested before reference:[link]https://github.com/sumitkumar33/Foundation2/blob/master/app/Http/Resources/UserStudentResource.php

Comment: Is that data coming from the Database? You have a posts table and a tags table. Each post has many tags. (One to many Relationship). and you want to get data as a JSON from the backend and send it to the front end. A post with all its tags?

That's what I understand by this. Is that correct or is it something other?

Comment: @UsmanKhan Yes it is comming from db. Each post has many tags and eachy tag has many posts (many to many). No, im not intrested in front end, i just want to get what i described in question. A post with corresponding tags and title, id and slug of each tag that belongs to that post.

Comment: @Sumitkumar Im not handling anything with post metod nor i have users that can upload posts from forms. i just have artificial db filled with factory seeds and im trying to get response like one i described in 1st code section. I will now look into github you linked and see if it helps me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Post Model

```
function tags(){
   return $this->hasMany(Tag::class);
}
```

In Tag Model

```
function posts(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

Then fetch data like this

```
$post = \App\Models\Post::with('tags')
    ->where('id', '=', 2)
    ->get();
    return $post;
```

It will give you as an array formatted as you need.
[image: Output]

also you can explicitly insert data: in front if you need.
like this.

```
return 'data: ' . $post;
```

in your case

```
public function toArray($request)
{
$post = \App\Models\Post::with('tags')
    ->where('id', '=', $this->id)// Replace according to your need.
    ->get();
return $post;
}
```

Comment: Nice this works, only what troubles me now is there an elegant way of removing unecesery data like "post_id", "created_at" and "updated_at" from tags? If using SQL i simply wouldnt mention those fields in SELECT statement, since your solution is saving sql statement in variable that returns everything ( select * from ....  ) so is there kind of query filter in laravel?

Comment: i just found in docs i can use select(), whereColumn(), like() and other SQL statements :D tnx man for bringig it up

Comment: You can select with select() function or just leave them as they are. Just not use them where you are using this array.   You can access each property of post as $post->title, 
$post->tags. remember tags is a collection (Array) you need to explicitly access it like $post->tags[0]->slug;   or use foreach ($post->tags as $tag) { process each one of them in body } .

And appreciated if you accept this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, i rly do appreciate your help.